# Created formula field based on condition

Tags: formula-field

I have a picklist field Source, When the Source field value is 'Social' then the formula should Concatenate the value using 3 fields
field 1 = work start date -  Date type,
field 2 = Emp number - Text Type,
field 3 = Absence - Text Type,

Tried to concatenate 3 fields, getting syntax error

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Source__c, 'WorkDay'),
    Work_Start_Date__c + DS_Employee_Number__c + DS_Absence_Type__c,
    ''
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace fields by API Name of your fields -

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Source, 'Social'), TEXT(Work_Start_Date__c) & DS_Employee_Number__c & DS_Absence_Type__c, '')
```

The return type should be text. You have to use TEXT function to convert the Date into text.